# One-to-One and Onto Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Please let me know if I did this question correctly. Thank You!

Let T be the linear transformation determined by

$$A =\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    5 & 6 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$$

a) State the domain of T and the codomain of T.

b) Determine whether T is one-to-one and whether it is onto. Justify your answers.

A)
Domain=2, Co-Domain=3

B)

ONE-TO-ONE

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    5 & 6 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$$
Row reduced echelon form is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$$

$x_1=0$

$x_2=0$

$0=0$

Since there are trivial solutions and independent columns *T* is one-to-one

ONTO

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    5 & 6 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$$
Row reduced echelon form is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$$

There are two pivot entries and two pivot columns. The Rank(A)=2, which does not equal the co-domain. This concludes that *T* is not onto.

**CONCLUSION**

A) Domain=2, Co-Domain=3

B) *T* is one-to-one but not onto

Comment: The statement "domain=2" does not make sense if taken literally.  Could you tell us what this is supposed to mean?

Comment: As I believe it domain is $R^n$

Comment: Do you mean to say that the domain is $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: I guess yeah that would make more sense after those changes does the process seem correct?

Comment: @D So if by "codomain=3" you similarly mean that the codomain is $\Bbb R^3$, yes: your solutions seems completely correct.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, of course.  I must not be fully awake yet.